# VS2019 Asp.NET Core 3.1 - HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have tried to run an asp.net core app in VS2019 using the IIS Express and I get the following error `HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure`

No logs nothing. When I got to the windows events I see the below error:

```
Application 'C:\SourceControl\MyProject1\src\MyProject1.Web\' failed to start. Exception message: Unable to find hostfxr directory at C:\SourceControl\MyProject1\src\MyProject1.Web\host\fxr
```

Can anyone advise on what is the problem?

Comment: Could you please tell me which OS you have used? If you used windows 7 ,it seems that you need to install the [OS update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26767).

Comment: I am using win10 Pro Version 1903 Build 18362.778